# Rich Calendar week number

Tags: calendar, richfaces

I'm wondering about disable the weekNumber in rich:calendar component of richfaces. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set

```
showWeeksBar="false"
```

on the `rich:calendar` tag